# Debug .NET WinForms applications under 120dpi

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging, dpi, highdpi

I currently use a VMware virtual machine (Windows XP) to debug my .NET WinForms applications under 120dpi. Very annoying.

Does anybody know a way that gives me similar results under my 96dpi working environment? That is, can 120dpi mode be activated for a single process, or is there a switch in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form Font property. By default WinForm form scale itself when Font property changed, something like that:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    Font = new Font("Arial", 14);
}
```

Don't forget to read about AutoScaleMode property and in general [about autoscaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229605.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: AutoScaleMode is set to Dpi. This is intended. So changing the font's size won't help.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to test application in high-dpi-like environment. I use this metodique for test my applications on working machine, prior to testing on high-dpi virtual machine.